# Android TabActivity with Google Maps and phone Camera

Tags: android, google-maps, android-camera, tabactivity

I'm newbie, I'm preparing my first Android application and I have a problem with putting features together.

I have application with four tabs (`TabActivity`), two (1st and 4th) are only static, but in 2nd should be phone front camera (like a mirror) and in 3rd should be Google Maps API v2 with markers. Everything works separated fine, but when I choose 2nd tab with mirror, and then 3rd tab with Google maps there is an error. Maps don't display. Same problem is when I close the application and try it again, but at first I open 3rd tab with Google Maps (works fine) and then tap to 2nd tab with mirror and nothing change, I see still maps (but I can't zoom it etc.).

I thing, I need something, when I tap to another tab, the mirror is killed (maybe maps too), but I can't find how can I do it. Maybe something about `surfaceDestroyed()`?

Here is MainActivity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

    //tab1 - static text
    TabSpec tab1spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1");
    tab1spec.setIndicator("One", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pin_empty));
    Intent tab1Intent = new Intent(this, Tab1Activity.class);
    tab1spec.setContent(tab1Intent);

    //tab2 - mirror
    TabSpec tab2spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2");
    tab2spec.setIndicator("Mirror", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pin_empty));
    Intent tab2Intent = new Intent(this, CameraActivity.class);
    tab2spec.setContent(tab2Intent);

    //tab3 - Google maps
    TabSpec tab3spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab3");
    tab3spec.setIndicator("Map", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pin_empty));
    Intent tab3Intent = new Intent(this, GoogleMapsActivity.class);
    tab3spec.setContent(tab3Intent);

    //tab4 - static text
    TabSpec tab4spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab4");
    tab4spec.setIndicator("Four", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pin_empty));
    Intent tab4Intent = new Intent(this, Tab4Activity.class);
    tab4spec.setContent(tab4Intent);

    tabHost.addTab(tab1spec);
    tabHost.addTab(tab2spec);
    tabHost.addTab(tab3spec);
    tabHost.addTab(tab4spec);
}
```

Here are two screenshots. I clicked to 3rd tab (maps) and then to 2nd tab (mirror), but I still see maps, no my face in the mirror:

1/ http://krispin.cz/_/so/TabActivity_problem-map.png
[image]
2/ http://krispin.cz/_/so/TabActivity_problem-mirror.png
[image]